# aligning multiple 3D cameras

Tags: ros, kinect, robot-calibration, camera-pose-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, we want to use several 3D cameras (including a couple of Xtions and a couple of Kinects etc.) to capture a whole room. The cameras are rigidly attached to a frame around the outside of the room, all facing inwards toward the center. We input some approximate relative camera poses already but the poses need to be properly aligned/calibrated (hopefully using a single fixed double-sided checkerboard in the center which they can all see at the same time).

The question is: what's the best package to calibrate the camera poses?

Is it possible to use the robot_calibration package. it seems to be more designed to calibrate using a moving arm and therefore expects to calibrate a using a series of poses from a bag, but since our "robot" doesn't move perhaps its possible to just not give it a bag, or to give it a bag with one pose and zero joints?

Perhaps some other package exists... I read the readme for camera_pose_calibration but found it quite confusing

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253974/aligning-multiple-3d-cameras/) by [Benjamint](https://answers.ros.org/users/29272/benjamint/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if [ethz-asl/kalibr](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr) and / or [industrial_extrinsic_cal](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_extrinsic_cal) suit your needs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benjamint](https://answers.ros.org/users/29272/benjamint/) on 2017-02-08**:
thanks, tomorrow ill let you know if it works. any idea whether robot_calibration with one pose and no joints would work? that's the preferred solution if its possible

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-08**:
I can't comment on whether `robot_calibration` can do this. Perhaps you could ask on the issue tracker.

**Comment by [Benjamint](https://answers.ros.org/users/29272/benjamint/) on 2017-02-10**:
unfortunately industrial_extrinsic_cal is out, it had heaps of problems and when it eventually worked it didn't do a great job. where is the issue tracker?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-10**:
The repository link is listed on the wiki page. That also hosts the tracker: [industrial_calibration/issues](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_calibration/issues).